# Bash how to find a pattern after a pattern

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed, grep

So I am trying to find a pattern after specific pattern

For example the input file would be

```
/wav1/af_ZA_IT_001_B.wav;2.98;3.67;;;dáár wav1
/wav1/af_ZA_IT_001_B.wav;2.98;3.67;;;dáár we1
/wav1/af_ZA_IT_001_B.wav;4.05;7.9;;;dit is franko wav1 van niekerk hier en kobus buys kobus
```

Then the output file would look for `wav1` after `;;;`

with using

```
grep "wav1" file.txt
```

I get all wav1 highlighted.

```
/wav1/af_ZA_IT_001_B.wav;2.98;3.67;;;dáár wav1
/wav1/af_ZA_IT_001_B.wav;2.98;3.67;;;dáár we1
/wav1/af_ZA_IT_001_B.wav;4.05;7.9;;;dit is franko wav1 van niekerk hier en kobus buys kobus
```

However since every file starts with wav1 I cannot find where wav1 is located after `;;;`.

How do I find a pattern ('wav`') after a pattern (';;;')

Expected output would be

```
/wav1/af_ZA_IT_001_B.wav;2.98;3.67;;;dáár wav1
/wav1/af_ZA_IT_001_B.wav;4.05;7.9;;;dit is franko wav1 van niekerk hier en kobus buys kobus
```

Comment: Could you please post sample of expected output in your question and let us know then.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Done!

Answer (score 5):

Easily with `grep`;

```
grep ';;;.*wav' file.txt
```

If you have `grep -P` you can use fancy Perl regex tricks; the following will only highlight the actual `wav` match:

```
grep -P ';;;.*\Kwav' file.txt
```

If you want to extract only the part after `;;;` you can use `sed`;

```
sed -n 's/.*;;;//;/wav/p' file.txt
```

Single quotes are generally preferable around regular expressions to avoid having the shell mess with the regex (double quotes are weaker, and won't protect backslashes, backticks, or many dollar signs).

Answer (score 3):

With GNU grep, match `;;;`, then any text with `.*` and then match `wav1` using `\bwav1\b` to make sure you do not match `wav12`:

```
grep -P ';;;.*\bwav1\b' yourfile.txt
```

`P` option means PCRE engine will be used.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that

```
grep -e ";;;.*wav.*" yourfile.txt
```

would suffice.

Comment: The trailing `.*` is superfluous. I believe the OP wants to find `wav`, not `wav1`.